# Domain redirecting without my permission

Tags: dns, redirect

http://catbreedsinformation.com

A friend and I put that site together a few years ago, just to do some study on how to use google ranking. It was actually doing quite well. Recently, we haven't really messed with it, but I still check the analytics, and they have severely dropped.

I went to visit the site tonight, and it loads for a split second, and then redirects me to a completely different site.

Can anyone explain what is causing this? And also, explain how I can stop this?

thanks.

Comment: This is a Wordpress hack. First of all, change your admin credentials on your Wordpress.
Run a security audit with any plugin (Sucuri works good), and clean up malware code (Not sure of any free plugins to do so).
Results from scan: https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/catbreedsinformation.com

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your website hacked.
First of all, please change all passwords. Then remove `twitter fan box plugin` (because script of this plugin is causing redirect)

Then you can check this resource: https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked